# DllImport Based on OS Platform

Tags: c#, interop

I have a mixture of unmanaged code ( backend) and managed code ( front end), as such, I would need to call the unmanaged code from my managed code, using interop techniques and `DllImport` attribute.

Now, I've compiled two versions of unmanaged code, for both 32 and 64 bit OS; they are named `service32.dll` and `service64.dll` respectively. So, in my .Net code, I would have to do a `DllImport` for both dlls:

```
[DllImport(@"service32.dll")]   //for 32 bit OS invocation
public static void SimpleFunction();

[DllImport(@"service64.dll")]   //for 64 bit OS invocation
public static void SimpleFunction();
```

And call them depending on which platform my application is running on.

The issue now is that for every unmanaged function, I have to declared it twice, one for 32 bit OS and one for 64 bit OS. This is a duplication of work, and everytime I change the signature of an unmanaged function, I have to modified it in two places.

Is there anyway that I can change the argument in `DllImport` so that the correct dll will be invoked automagically, depending on the platform?

Comment: It doesn't look much like Fortran to me.

Comment: @High, the code is C#, interop code.

Comment: that's what it looked like to me, couldn't understand the Fortran tag.

Comment: Removed the fortran tag, for I see no connection to it by anything in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Don't think that DllImport supports that, You could just call LoadLibrary etc manually.

But take a look at [Parameterising DllImport for use in a C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660761/parameterising-dllimport-for-use-in-a-c-application) the answers there would also suit you.